# Is there need to change application server web.config?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm with 2 WFEs and one application server.
I have made some custom changes to  web.config file of one web application on one WFE server and performed same action on another WFE server as well.

Should i perform same action on Application server as well?

Comment: You have mentioned 2 WFE and One APP Server . Is the Appserver clubbed in one of the WFE or as a seperate server?

Answer (score 1):

In fact you should not do the changes on any of them, but use [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to make the change on all servers (including future) for you.

If you really need to make the change by hand then you should probably also do it on the App server, as it hopefully works as WFE for crawling.

Comment: A lot of people don't trust SPWebConfigModification because of its low reliability, and its complexity in some case.

Comment: A lot of people don't trust SharePoint because of its low reliability, and its complexity in some case. But I still think it's a great tool and the same goes for SPWebConfigModification, but yes it requires thought to get the Name right.